# Python 2.7 : How to constrain the delimiter of a new line to be '\n' on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

When I write into a text file within a python 2.7 script that runs on Windows the new line delimiter is `'\r\n'`, but I would like it to be `'\n'`.

I have tried to use [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) with `newline='\n'`, but it raised an exception.

```
import io
f= io.open("myfile.txt", "w", newline="\n")
f.write(”aaaaaaa”)
f.close()
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you opened the file? What exception did using the newline parameter raise?

Comment: `replace('\r\n', '\n')`

Comment: I mean where you used `open`.

Comment: The newline argument doesn't exist for the open function in version 2.7.  That is why you got the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me and writes using `\n` instead of `\r\n`

```
 import io
 f= io.open("myfile.txt", "w", newline="\n")
 #note the io module requires you to write unicode
 f.write(unicode("asdasd\nasdasasd\n"))
 f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `open("file.ext", "wb")` to open the file in binary mode, you will have your desired behavior. The conversion of `"\n"` to `"\r\n"` is only done:

- if you're on Windows and
- open your file in text mode, i.e. `open("file.ext", "w")`