# How to add content on every line of file in python?

Tags: python

I have .dat file with atleast 100k lines. I want to add some content at end of every line using python. I have multiples of .dat files, if possible, let me know how to process all files with this adding content at end of line and saving them to another directory.

Comment: Yeah.  Show us what you've tried or what you're thinking.  Hint: open input and output files, then in loop: read line from input, modify line, write line to output.

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are inside one directory, you can get all those files with the `glob` module, else you will need to walk the directories with `os.walk` from the `os` module.

Then you will iterate over every filename which you get from the above functions.

In this iteration you will first create a new file in another directory (`open(..., 'w+')`), and then open the file you want to modify (`open(..., 'r')`).

Then you will start iterating over the content of the file whose content you want to modify:

```
with open(target, 'w+') as tf:
  with open(source, 'r') as sf:
    for line in sf:
      tf.write(line[:-1] + ' appended content\n')
```

The `[:-1]` removes the newline (\n) in the current line, you may need to use `[:-2]` if your files contain \r\n as newlines.

`for line in sf:` uses a generator, which means that the source file's content is not loaded completely into memory at the beginning, but only what is currently needed.

Comment: " you may need to use [:-2] if your files contain \r\n as newlines": no as text mode strips `\r`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. But i'm a bit confused now because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/14754094/277267

Comment: The binary mode questions all have to do with if you're dealing with Windows files, and just HOW you want to deal with them. I don't see any mention of Windows here, so maybe it doesn't matter.  If you are reading text files, you usually want to use "r" and "w".  This will do the "right thing" with the EOL characters for the platform you're on.  You'll read any type of file, and you'll write files for the platform you're on.  The only gotcha here is if you're on one platform and want to write files in the format for another platform, and adding "b" won't help with that.

Comment: @JoeAdmin Yes, I do this a lot, have a ton of scripts write text files on Windows and read them on Linux and the other way around as well, maybe that caused my confusion which lead me to settle with always double checking what the endings are and using `[:-1]`/`[:-2]` as needed. But now knowing what text variants of `open` do may help me a bit with this.

Comment: Yeah, "r" insures that you always have just '\n' at the end of your lines